# Magento 2.4.5 - get order id in transactional email html

Tags: magento2, order-email

How can I get the actual order id (not increment id) in a transactional email?
I have tried the following but none of them return the order id:

```
{{var order.getId()}}
{{var order.getOrderId()}}
{{var order.id()}}
{{var order_id}}
{{var $order.id}}
```

Thanks

Magento 2.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also checked this and while debugging i got to know that from this path = vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php they are setting the order_id data on line no 129 of function prepareTemplate if you have xdebug it is better to check it . Please check the code screenshot

[image]

And in the HTML templates of order email related you can just use like this as example here =

```
<p>{{var order_id}}</p>
```

This will work , please let me know if it doesn't , and also please do give a  like as this helps to answer more questions.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to solve this using the same method you suggest. I was using a 3rd party module and they didn't pass the order_id var to the transport. I added this and it works correctly now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have you helped, have a nice day.